# Angular 2 Get mat-dialog-container nativeelement

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 material mat-dialogs. Now i want to access the mat-dialog-container native element.

```
let nElem = this.dialogRef._containerInstance._elementRef.nativeElement;
```

When i try to access native element as above i am getting error "Property _elementRef" is private and only accessible within class 'MatDialogContainer'

Example: - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5mgjl

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to get the native element of the Mat Dialog is by using ViewContainerRef. To my understanding the ViewContainerRef when used in the constructor will get the reference of the container of this component. In your case it would be the Mat Dialog Container.

The following works:

```
import { ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';


constructor(private _ViewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { 

}

ngOnInit() {
  let matDialogContainerRef = this._ViewContainerRef.element.nativeElement;
}
```

On Another fun note this can be used to easily identify whether a click happened inside or outside the Dialog.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
clickout(event) {
  if(this.vcRef.element.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
    alert('Clicked inside');
  } else {
    alert('Clicked outside');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in Angular 5 project

```
 let nElem = dialogRef['_containerInstance']['_elementRef'].nativeElement;
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Hello Dimitri your answer did work however it is not good to go into private variables like that.

Comment: Would this work in a `--prod` build? I'm guessing not, certainly in current Angular